# I have no CiviCRM menu when using Shoreditch

Tags: theme, bootstrap, shoreditch

CiviCRM 4.7.25 with Drupal 7: I have no CiviCRM menu when I use the Shoreditch Bootstrap theme in CiviCRM. Anyone else had this problem and fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

I would guess it is related to https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.shoreditch/pull/90#issuecomment-343347028 and the PR seems to solve that.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer Thomas, no luck yet with this patch